docs changes in a specific collection in firebase in my flutter app
I have already implemented the logic but when the listener triggered after updating only one document or adding or deleting it the whole docs fetched to me but is their any way to fetch only the updated doc.
here's the provider
class OfferProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  final OffersService _offerService = OffersService();
  List<Offer> _offers = [];

  List<Offer> get offers => _offers;

  OfferProvider() {
    _listenToOffers();
  }

  void _listenToOffers() {
    _offerService.getOffers().listen((offersData) {
      _offers = offersData;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
}

here's the service that talks to firestore
class OffersService {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  /// Retrieves a stream of offers from the Firestore database.
  ///
  /// Returns a stream of lists of `Offer` objects, where each list represents a snapshot of the 'offers' collection.
  ///
  /// The stream is updated in real-time as the data in the Firestore database changes.
  Stream<List<Offer>> getOffers() {
    return _firestore.collection('offers').snapshots().map((snapshot) {
      return snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Offer.fromFirestore(doc)).toList();
    });
  }
}

thanks in advance
i tried to add the following code and get the updated snapshot but with the data recieved from firestore, all the docs are fetched again with it:
provider
 void _listenToOffers() {
    _offerService.getOffers().listen((snapshot) {
      for (var change in snapshot.docChanges) {
        switch (change.type) {
          case DocumentChangeType.added:
            // Handle added documents
            _offers.add(Offer.fromFirestore(change.doc));
            break;
          case DocumentChangeType.modified:
            // Handle modified documents
            int index =
                _offers.indexWhere((offer) => offer.id == change.doc.id);
            if (index != -1) {
              _offers[index] = Offer.fromFirestore(change.doc);
            }
            break;
          case DocumentChangeType.removed:
            // Handle removed documents
            _offers.removeWhere((offer) => offer.id == change.doc.id);
            break;
        }
      }
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

service
class OfferService {
  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> getOffers() {
    return _firestore
        .collection('offers')
        .where('activated', isEqualTo: true)
        .snapshots();
  }
}


It's expected that Firestore query listeners return all of the matching documents for a query in each callback every time one of those documents changes.  If you want to know which ones changed since the last time your listener was called, you have to look at the change type for each document in the query snapshot.


the whole docs fetched to me
...
all the docs are fetched again with it

The Firestore client actually only fetches the modified documents from the database server. But the API raises a query snapshot with both the modified and the unmodified documents. If you want to distinguish between those, look at the change type in the docChanges array (as Doug commented).

thank you very much for the clarification, understood
